# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array when trying to use TextLMDataBunch.from_csv in FastAI

Tags: encoding, ascii, utf, fast-ai

The library expects `utf-8`. I tried to convert my us-ascii file to `utf-8` using:

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 src.csv > target.csv
```

When I did:

```
file -I target.csv
```

It still showed charset as us-ascii. Then I found out that us-ascii is a subset of utf-8 and that file will only guess the file type.

However, if I take use src.csv as input to the TextLMDataBunch.from_csv() library, it works. If I do:

```
cat src.csv > target.csv
```

And then use target.csv as input to the same library, it doesn't work and gives the following error:

```
   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-44bc7147d2a4> in <module>()
----> 1 data_lm = TextLMDataBunch.from_csv(sample_p, 'voila.csv')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/text/data.py in from_csv(cls, path, csv_name, valid_pct, test, tokenizer, vocab, classes, header, text_cols, label_cols, label_delim, **kwargs)
    180         test_df = None if test is None else pd.read_csv(Path(path)/test, header=header)
    181         return cls.from_df(path, train_df, valid_df, test_df, tokenizer, vocab, classes, text_cols,
--> 182                            label_cols, label_delim, **kwargs)
    183 
    184     @classmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/text/data.py in from_df(cls, path, train_df, valid_df, test_df, tokenizer, vocab, classes, text_cols, label_cols, label_delim, **kwargs)
    165         src = ItemLists(path, TextList.from_df(train_df, path, cols=text_cols, processor=processor),
    166                         TextList.from_df(valid_df, path, cols=text_cols, processor=processor))
--> 167         src = src.label_for_lm() if cls==TextLMDataBunch else src.label_from_df(cols=label_cols, classes=classes, sep=label_delim)
    168         if test_df is not None: src.add_test(TextList.from_df(test_df, path, cols=text_cols))
    169         return src.databunch(**kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py in _inner(*args, **kwargs)
    356         assert isinstance(fv, Callable)
    357         def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
--> 358             self.train = ft(*args, **kwargs)
    359             assert isinstance(self.train, LabelList)
    360             self.valid = fv(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/text/data.py in label_for_lm(self, **kwargs)
    285         "A special labelling method for language models."
    286         self.__class__ = LMTextList
--> 287         return self.label_const(0, label_cls=LMLabel)
    288 
    289     def reconstruct(self, t:Tensor):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py in label_const(self, const, **kwargs)
    211     def label_const(self, const:Any=0, **kwargs)->'LabelList':
    212         "Label every item with `const`."
--> 213         return self.label_from_func(func=lambda o: const, **kwargs)
    214 
    215     def label_empty(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/data_block.py in label_from_func(self, func, **kwargs)
    219     def label_from_func(self, func:Callable, **kwargs)->'LabelList':
    220         "Apply `func` to every input to get its label."
--> 221         return self.label_from_list([func(o) for o in self.items], **kwargs)
    222 
    223     def label_from_folder(self, **kwargs)->'LabelList':

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong? I am trying this on Google Colab and tried the character encoding changes on Colab and on my Mac but with no results.

Comment: Different function but I get 0-length bugs too whenever TextLMDataBunch.from_folder() is called.  The lib might be unfinished. That's what it seems like.

Comment: If your input file is encoded in US-ASCII you can provided it as it is. In fact UTF-8 is  backward compatibility with ASCII.

As you get different behavior between your two files I guess that maybe `cat src.csv > target.csv` perform some incorrect change in the encoding. Using an hexadecimal editor to compare the beginning of the two files might help to figure out what goes wrong.